# ExtractTextPlugin and postCSS - autoprefixer not working

Tags: webpack, autoprefixer, postcss, webpack-plugin

I'm trying to setup webpack to have a compilation pass where it scans all css files in one file tree and then generates a css files with all the styles bundled, autoprefixed and minimised.

I can't get autoprefixer plugin to work.

Here is the relevant webpack config part:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const glob = require('glob')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

// postCSS plugins
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')

module.exports = [
{
  // another compilation pass
},
{
  name: 'static-css',
  entry: {
    vendor: glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'assets/stylesheets/vendor/**/*.css')),
    styles: glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'assets/stylesheets/src/**/*.css'))
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/stylesheets/build/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // css loader for custom css
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/stylesheets/src'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader')
      },
      // css loader for vendor css
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/stylesheets/vendor'),
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      // other loaders for images, fonts, and svgs
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
      }
    ],
    postcss: function() {
      return [
        autoprefixer
      ]
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    // extract css in a .css file
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ]
}
];
```

When I run webpack, I get all the files compressed in the bundle.js and correctly extracted in a separate `styles.css` file. But the vendor prefixes are not applied.

I'm using this class to test the prefixes:

```css
.autoprefixer-test {
  display: flex;
  transition: all .5s;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
  user-select: none;
}
```

I've tried to change the call to ExtractTextPlugin.extract like `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader'])` as seen in other posts, but it doesn't help at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you've misplaced the `postcss` parameters. According to the documentation at https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader the following code should be placed at the top level of your configuration and not under the `module` section:

```
postcss: function() {
  return [
    autoprefixer
  ]
}
```

**Update.**

In fact there is a lot more configuration to be written for this integration of postcss and webpack to work. Thanks to the following thread I've found the solution https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/8

First, in order for `postcss` to be able for work on `@import`'ed files, `postcss-import` plugin needs to be used. To integrate this plugin with webpack (eg. enable file watching for hot reloading or rebuilding), special parameter taken from initializer's function arguments is passed as an argument to `postcssImport` like this:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcssImport = require('postcss-import');
....
postcss: function(webpack) {
  return [
    postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webpack }), // should be first
    autoprefixer
  ];
]
```

Sadly, this breaks asset loading through webpack when using `url(...)` with relative paths. This happens because `postcss-import` merges all `@import`'ed files into one, but paths remain relative to files initial directories. In order to rewrite relative paths, `postcss-url` plugin should be used and  configuration now looks like this:

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcssImport = require('postcss-import');
var postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');
....
postcss: function(webpack) {
  return [
    postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webpack }),
    postcssUrl(),
    autoprefixer
  ];
]
```

Comment: God, I can't believe it was something as simple as the postcss option not being set at the right level... thanks mate. Also thanks for the other thoughts, not importing any css yet, but will definitely come in handy at some point.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining all of that.